# Python MYSQL update statement

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get this Python MYSQL update statement correct(With Variables):

```
cursor.execute ("UPDATE tblTableName SET Year=%s" % Year ", Month=%s" % Month ", Day=%s" % Day ", Hour=%s" % Hour ", Minute=%s" Minute "WHERE Server=%s " % ServerID)
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

It [should be](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html):

```
cursor.execute ("""
   UPDATE tblTableName
   SET Year=%s, Month=%s, Day=%s, Hour=%s, Minute=%s
   WHERE Server=%s
""", (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, ServerID))
```

You can **also** do it with basic string manipulation,

```
cursor.execute ("UPDATE tblTableName SET Year=%s, Month=%s, Day=%s, Hour=%s, Minute=%s WHERE Server='%s' " % (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, ServerID))
```

but **[this way is discouraged because it leaves you open for SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)**. As it's so easy (and similar) to do it the *right way*<sup>tm</sup>. Do it correctly.

The only thing you should be careful, is that some database backends don't follow the same convention for string replacement (SQLite comes to mind).

Comment: Paolo's answer is better. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307378/python-mysql-update-statement/1307413#1307413

Comment: But this one will work with every backend. This version doesn't do any validation on the input, while Paolo's way will make sure to escape the variables content.

Comment: Do *not* do it this way. You leave yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks. Paulo has the right answer, because it ensures that the values are properly escaped before passing them to the db.

Comment: Ripped off Paolo's answer, as I can't delete accepted answer.

Comment: the triple double-quotes is mandatory? If yes what is their purpose?

Comment: @dios231 the triple quotes allow you to write multiline strings. If you were to print the `repr` of the above text it would be:

`"\n   UPDATE tblTableName\n   SET Year=%s, Month=%s, Day=%s, Hour=%s, Minute=%s\n   WHERE Server=%s\n"`

Answer (score 54):

You've got the syntax all wrong:

```
cursor.execute ("""
   UPDATE tblTableName
   SET Year=%s, Month=%s, Day=%s, Hour=%s, Minute=%s
   WHERE Server=%s
""", (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, ServerID))
```

For more, [read the documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html).

Comment: does it matter if I use
""" update tblname ...""".format(var1, var2)
instead?

Comment: is there a way to find the message `rows affected` message which we can see in `MySQL workbench`

Answer (score 23):

Here is the correct way：

```
import MySQLdb

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306,
                              user="xxx", passwd="xxx", db='xxx', charset='utf8')

    cursor = connect.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
       UPDATE tblTableName
       SET Year=%s, Month=%s, Day=%s, Hour=%s, Minute=%s
       WHERE Server=%s
    """, (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, ServerID))

    connect.commit()
    connect.close()
```

P.S. Don't forget `connect.commit()`, or it won't work

Comment: yes commit is needed. As in my case without commit, it was putting a lock on whole table and then definitely no query was working on that table.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of them worked for me for some reason.

I figured it out that for some reason python doesn't read %s. So use (?) instead of %S in you SQL Code.

And finally this worked for me.

```
   cursor.execute ("update tablename set columnName = (?) where ID = (?) ",("test4","4"))
   connect.commit()
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You have to commit on connection, not on cursor. connection.commit() will do.

Answer (score 0):

@Esteban Küber is absolutely right.

Maybe one additional hint for bloody beginners like me.
If you **speciify the variables with %s**, you have to follow this principle
**for EVERY input value**, which means for the SET-variables as well as for the WHERE-variables.

Otherwise, you will have to face a termination message like
**'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s WHERE'**