# Mysql Update Syntax Error Python

Tags: python, sql-update, mysql-python

I've been following this previous answer, however I still get a syntax error:

[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1307413/578582)

```
    cursor.execute ("""
   UPDATE tblTableName
   SET Year=%s, Month=%s, Day=%s, Hour=%s, Minute=%s
   WHERE Server=%s
   """, (Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, ServerID))
```

My code is:

```
def postToMySQL(data,fieldname,table,col):
if fieldname == "Year":
    sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " ("+ fieldname + ") VALUES (%s)"
    c.execute(sql, data)
else:
    c.execute ("""
   UPDATE %s
   SET US=%s
   WHERE ID=%s
    """, (table, data, col))
```

The table then looks like:

[image: Stack Overflow Answer]

The syntax error is:

> _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064....near ''OilProvedReservesHistory' SET US = '36.533' WHERE ID=1' at line 1

Can you spot the error? ?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this, without the quotes

SET US = '36.533'

Can you try this:

```
UPDATE %s
   SET US=%s
   WHERE ID=%s
```

Comment: Cheers. I tried that before posting, but neglected to check that the error is different. It's now throwing up: TyperError: not all agruments converted during string formatting

Comment: Scratch that, removing fieldname from the list still gives the error: ''OilProvedReservesHistory'\n\t   SET US = '36.533'\n\t   WHERE ID=1'. Is it something to do with the \n\t business?

Comment: I don't think the \n\t matters because I tried putting it all on one line and the error becomes: ''OilProvedReservesHistory' SET US='36.533' WHERE ID=1' at line 1

Comment: Ah, thanks to feco, but it works if I put in the table name explicitly ie:

    else:
  c.execute ("""
    UPDATE OilProvedReservesHistory
    SET US=%s
    WHERE ID=%s
  """, (data, col))

Can someone explain why this  is the case? Do I have to do the brute force string concatenation that I have done like this each time?

    sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " ("+ fieldname + ") VALUES (%s)"

Comment: There is a ' after 'OilProvedReservesHistory, be careful using the ' because it means a varchar in SQL, try to concatenate your string before entering into SQL, and make sure there a no orphan '