# Update specific cell in mySQL using python

Tags: python, mysql-python

I've been using mySQLdb in python to import data into a database, however I would also like to be able to address a specific row and update a cell in that row, I couldn't find the command to do this in the mySQLdb help file, would anyone be kind enough to point me in the right direction...

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sql [UPDATE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp) statement

psuedo data schema:

```
# table people
id INT, name VARCHAR(40), age INT, address VARCHAR(100)

1, john, 33, North America
2, dm03514, 28, Maryland
```

using pythong [MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307378/python-mysql-update-statement)

```
cursor.execute('UPDATE people SET address = %s WHERE id = %s', ('Columbia, MD', 2));
```