# Python: Iterating through MySQL columns

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm wondering if you can help me. I'm trying to change the value in each column if the text matches a corresponding keyword. This is the loop:

```
for i in range(0, 20, 1):
    cur.execute("UPDATE table SET %s = 1 WHERE text rlike %s") %(column_names[i], search_terms[i])
```

The MySQL command works fine on its own, but not when I put it in the loop. It's giving an error at the first `%s`

Does anyone have any insights?

This is the error:

```
_mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s = 1 WHERE text rlike %s' at line 1")
```

Column names looks like

```
column_names = ["col1","col2","col3"...]
```

Search terms look like

```
search_terms = ["'(^| |.|-)word1[;:,. ?-]'","'(^| |.|-)word2[;:,. ?-]'",...]
```

Comment: show column_names and search_terms

Comment: why do you have range(0, 20, 1)? thats the same as just range(20) or even range(0, 20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do this is to give values to Python, which will quote things correctly.

adapted from voyager's [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1307400/143880):

```
for i in range(0, 20, 1):
    cur.execute("UPDATE table SET {} = 1 WHERE text rlike %s".format(column_names[i]),
                (search_terms[i],),
               )
```

In this case it's confusing because the `column_name` isn't a value, it's part of the table structure, so it's inserted using good old string formatting.  The `search_term` is a value, so is passed to `cursor.execute()` for correct, safe quoting.

(Don't use string manipulation to add the quotes -- you're exposing yourself to SQL injection.)

Comment: Thank you! This works for me. I dont fully understand the syntax you've used, but I'll spend the time now, while this does its text searches to try and see what you've done there.

Answer (score 0):

Missing quotes and wrong parenthesis placement...

```
for i in range(0, 20, 1):
    cur.execute("UPDATE table SET %s = 1 WHERE text rlike '%s'" %(column_names[i], search_terms[i]))
#                                                         ^  ^
#              (-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------)
```

Please note, this is **not** the right way of doing this, **if** your string may contain quotes by itself...

What about that instead:

```
for i in range(0, 20, 1):
    cur.execute("UPDATE table SET %s = 1 WHERE text rlike ?" % (column_names[i],),
                (search_terms[i],))
```

This uses the `%` operator to set the column name, but uses an `executes` parameter to bind the data, letting the DB driver escape all characters that need so.