# Python SQL Update Syntax Issues

Tags: python, sqlite, prepared-statement

Hello I was following [Python MYSQL update statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307378/python-mysql-update-statement) and managed to produce this code for my programme's SQL Update with variables function:

```
def editInfo(start, userName):
    newFavGenre = input("Enter your favourite genre")
    newFavArtist = input("Enter your favourite artist")
    ## userName is a global variable
    con = lite.connect(db)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute ("""
    UPDATE users
    SET favGenre=%s, favArtist=%s
    WHERE username=%s
""", (newFavGenre, newFavArtist, userName))
    results = cur.fetchall()
    return result
    mainmenu()
```

And keep expericiencing this error code:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It appears the post you are looking at is for MySQL and I conjecture that you're using the `sqlite3` python interface based on your error.

Looking at the [sqlite3 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html)...

```
cur.execute("""
    UPDATE users
    SET favGenre=%s, favArtist=%s
    WHERE username=%s
""", (newFavGenre, newFavArtist, userName))
```

Should instead be

```
cur.execute("""
    UPDATE users
    SET favGenre=?, favArtist=?
    WHERE username=?
    """, (newFavGenre, newFavArtist, userName))
```

You could also use their named style which instead of taking a tuple takes a dictionary.

```
cur.execute("""
    UPDATE users
    SET favGenre=:genre, favArtist=:artist
    WHERE username=:username
""", {'genre':newFavGenre, 'artist': newFavArtist, 'username':userName})
```